# Association table records deleted when deleting referenced records in JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a table **student** and a table **course**, which are referenced by an association table **student_course**. This is what the entities look like

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "id",
            strategy = "com.something.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    private UUID id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "student_course",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    private List<Course> courses;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @OrderBy("sequenceNumber ASC")
    private List<StudentCourse> studentCourses;
}

@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "id",
            strategy = "com.something.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    private UUID id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
    private List<Student> students;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    @OrderBy("sequenceNumber ASC")
    private List<StudentCourses> studentCourses;
}

@Entity
public class StudentCourse {
    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentCourseId studentCourseId;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("studentId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("courseId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;
    private Long sequenceNumber;
}

@Embeddable
public class StudentCourseId implements Serializable {
    private UUID studentId;
    private UUID courseId;
}
```

I have no cascade constraint on the tables, I tried deleting records from student with a query and records in which they were referenced in student_course were not deleted. If I use deleteById of StudentRepository though, also the records that reference them in student_course get deleted. I don't want that, I want to handle the deletion.

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, UUID> {
}
```

Do you know why that happens? I don't want the deletion of neither table's records to cascade.

I'm using PostgreSQL and 2.3.3.RELEASE of spring-boot-starter-parent.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a Many To Many relationship between the student and course entities. Please consider removing the one to many relationship, also there is no need to create a StudentCourse entity, hibernate will detect your student_course table. lets consider a many to many mapping between a customer and a product.

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customers")
private List product;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
name = "customer_product",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"))
private List customers;

Here customer is the owning side of the relationship.

Comment: Will this fix the issue?

Comment: yes it should, lets give it a try.